# fatal error: avr/io.h: No such file or directory compilation terminated

Tags: ubuntu

I am use **14.04 version of Ubuntu**. Whenever i run **AVR** program this kind of error is generating "fatal error: avr/io.h: No such file or directory. compilation terminated".

So, please someone help me how to include **avr/io.h** file in the **GCC** compiler.

Comment: sudo aptitude install avr-libc -- from Google search result http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1014673

Comment: Related: http://askubuntu.com/q/155088/323845

Answer (score 1):

You might have installed just gcc-avr. For getting all the device specific libraries you need to install avr-libc as well.

please try `sudo apt-get install avr-libc`